# Show that for $A, B \in 2^{X}$ The symmetric difference $A\bigtriangleup B = C\bigtriangleup D \Leftrightarrow A\bigtriangleup C = B\bigtriangleup D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that for $A,B \in 2^X$ we have the following equivalence: $A\bigtriangleup B=C\bigtriangleup D \Leftrightarrow A\bigtriangleup C=B\bigtriangleup D$, where $\bigtriangleup$ represents the symmetric difference operator.

We have $A \bigtriangleup A = \varnothing$ as well as the notion of distributivity and associativity. Then I thought I could do something like "solving" the equations using these notions.

First, we apply $\bigtriangleup C$ to both sides of $A\bigtriangleup B=C\bigtriangleup D$, yielding $A\bigtriangleup B \bigtriangleup C =C\bigtriangleup D \bigtriangleup C = (C\bigtriangleup C)\bigtriangleup D = D$.
Similarly we apply $\bigtriangleup B$ to $A\bigtriangleup C=B\bigtriangleup D$, that is $A \bigtriangleup B \bigtriangleup C = D$.

Is my reasoning correct and complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the algebraic approach ($\Delta$ being an self-inverse Abelian group operation on sets with identity $\emptyset$) works fine here:

If $A \Delta B = C\Delta D$ then $(A \Delta B) \Delta C = (C \Delta D) \Delta  C = (C \Delta C) \Delta D = \emptyset \Delta D = D$ and applying $B$ to both sides: $((A \Delta B) \Delta C) \Delta B = A \Delta C = B \Delta D$ etc. The reverse goes the same way.

$A \Delta B = C \Delta D$ is the same as $A \Delta B \Delta C \Delta D = \emptyset$ really: no point is in any odd number of $A,B,C,D$ at the same time.